# Cookies not passing into post request headers

Tags: cookies, axios, cors, csrf, flask-cors

I'm currently using Vue/Axios on the frontend, and I'm trying to hook up some api endpoints that require a session cookie to be passed into the request headers. The backend is built using Python/Flask. The issue arises when I run a request and no cookies are being passed into the request headers.

The dev server I'm attempting to use has the following CORS headers set: `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:5173`, (this is the correct port for my environment. On the frontend, I have configured axios `withCredentials: true`. Despite all of this, there are no cookies being passed into the request headers, and I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: What is the server's Web origin? If it's not of the form`http://localhost:xxx`, what is the value of the cookies of interest's `SameSite` attribute? And if that attribute is empty, in what browser are you testing your client?

Comment: @jub0bs I can't say the exact domain, but the dev server is not on localhost. I've tested the cookie with SameSite set to nothing as well as None, with no luck either way. I'm testing in Chrome.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to set your cookie with `SameSite=None`. And for that to work in Chrome, you'll need to set the cookie with `Secure` also. Have you tried that?